# vim regular expreesion

Tags: regex, vim

How to find `<foo>` but not `<<foo>>` in following text:

---------`<foo>`--------

---------`<<foo>>`------

I try `/\(<<\)\@!\zsfoo`,it does't work correctly.
thanks

Comment: Here, the question is, do you want to also find `<<foo` and ``foo>>``? Also, what is `foo`? A literal string? Or anything between `<` and `>`?

Comment: I want to find 'foo',a literal string enclose by <>,but not <<>>.

Comment: Do you need to match `<foo>>` or `<<foo>`?

Comment: no,only 'foo' that enclose in <>. i.e. match 'foo' in the first line,not in the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
:g/\(<\)\@<!<foo>\(>\)\@!
```

Or, since `<` and `>` are single char strings, you may even discard the grouping parentheses:

```
:g/<\@<!<foo>>\@!
```

*Details*

- `\(<\)\@<!` / `<\@<!` - a location not immediately preceded with `<` char
- `<foo>` - a `<foo>` string
- `\(>\)\@!` / `>\@!` - immediately to the right, there must be no `>` char.